Литература по администрированию Windows
Есть потребность научиться умело обращаться с виндой. Нужна литература, такая чтоб могла дать базу для какого-нибудь системного администратора на винду, но так, чтобы без ненужного душного разбора ОС на атомы.
Какие цели я преследую: во-первых знать свой ПК как свои 5 пальцев и уметь решать нетривиальные проблемы. Во-вторых обладать той базой, которая позволит мне после универа, пойти джуном сисадмином, если так сложится судьба.
P.s.: На Unix у меня есть литература, но, если предложите что-то полезное для Linux - не откажусь

Я знаю, что можно просто загуглить. Но это равносильно тому, что вы будете искать фильм на вечер: можете случайное что-то включить, и не знать стоит ли он внимания, а можете спросить киноманов: что они порекомендуют?

Здесь есть какие-то ссылки на какие-то книги, но Вы же не думаете всерьёз, что эти книги хоть чем-то отличаются от загугленных только что Вами? Лично я книг не читал по Windows. Я просто в течение 30 лет устанавливал их пользователям, начиная с Windows 3.11. И делаю это до сих пор, не реже одного раза в месяц. До того я был пользователем - секретаршей - и делал очень сложные документы. Таким образом изучал MS Office. Непрерывно программировал, иногда переписывая готовые проекты с одного языка на другой. И книжки, книжки, книжки... Большая часть - мусор, но зёрна отделялись от плевел.

Советую пройти какие-нибудь Майкрософтовские курсы. Например, я в своё время проходил 50321 Windows 7 Configuring, Technology Specialist Course и аналогичные от NT до Windows 10 и по соотвествующим серверам и сетевой инфраструктуре. И, как пишет @FoxFox, практика нужна.

Вот, нашёл у себя: Джесси Торес. Скрипты для администратора Windows, 2002 г. Хоть и старая, но практически всё содержимое актуально.

https://rutracker.org/forum/index.php; https://nnmclub.to; https://www.e-reading.life

2002? Та ну, Windows уже совсем другой.

@FoxFox Что из этого вам кажется совсем другим?

Возьмите два компьютера. На одном установите Windows XP, а на другом Windows 11 24H2 со всеми обновлениями и разглядывайте разницу. А у меня нет времени на лекции, на адвокатство и на уговоры. Читайте то, что считаете нужным.
